# Exception while connecting my hibernate class to mysql

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting an exception while running a Hibernate code. I am very new to hibernate. Please let me know what am I missing.

```
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.Final}
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Employee.hbm.xml
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 13, 2013 5:53:41 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1822)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1780)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:319)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:149)
    ... 13 more
```

The class i used is  :

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();

      /* Add few employee records in database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);

      /* List down all the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();

      /* Update employee's records */
      ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);

      /* Delete an employee from the database */
      ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

      /* List down new list of the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();
   }
   /* Method to CREATE an employee in the database */
   public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }
   /* Method to  READ all the employees */
   public void listEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list(); 
         for (Iterator iterator = 
                           employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next(); 
            System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName()); 
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName()); 
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary()); 
         }
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to UPDATE salary for an employee */
   public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                    (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         employee.setSalary( salary );
         session.update(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to DELETE an employee from the records */
   public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                   (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         session.delete(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException:
>   Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded

This exception is due to `MySQL` driver. Load `MySQL` connector jar file on classpath.

Comment: which jar file should i download for this?

Comment: After adding the mysql connector to my classpath, am still not able to get rid of the error. I use the connector: mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin. I still have the same error, what other thing am i missing. Am using the same code as @anon

Answer (score 0):

You have no JDBC driver in the classpath as it is clearly stated in your error messages:

```
lassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded
```

or you have misspelled the JDBC driver name, but it seems ok.

Comment: Where would I find the driver?

Comment: On the MySQL Website Or in your Applications classpath during launch. You should Check your textbook from the Java class you take, I am sure classloading is mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error

> Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:18)

[image: Hibernate Program Connect With Mysql]

This error can be solved easily.

First you download `mysql-connector-java-3.0.16-ga-bin.jar`
After that, you add this jar file in your Hibernate program inside Libraries.
Right click on your program -> Build Path -> Add External Archive -> mysql-connector-java-3.0.16-ga-bin.jar
After that Run Program And Remove Error.

[image: Successfully connected Hibernate program connect with MySql]

Comment: Your answer is easily understand. And my problem solve. Thank you sir.